# Generic superclass "not defined" despite mypy being happy

Tags: python, generics, mypy

I've been struggling with strange situations where mypy is happy, but python crashes when I run the code. Here's an issue I'm having with generics. I have two files in the same directory. When I run python3 in `sample_parser.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joe/repos/ut-norm-james/so_generics/sample_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    class SampleParser(LookaheadParser[str]):
NameError: name 'LookaheadParser' is not defined
```

Here's `lookahead_parser.py`:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional, Callable


_T = TypeVar("_T")
StateFunc = Callable[[_T], Callable]


class LookaheadParser(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self._token_index: int = 0
        self._tokens: list[_T] = []
        self._state: StateFunc

    def _parse(self) -> None:
        while self._token_index < len(self._tokens):
            self._state = self._state(self._tokens[self._token_index])
            self._token_index += 1

    def _lookahead(self, offset: int) -> Optional[_T]:
        prospective_index = self._token_index + offset
        if prospective_index < len(self._tokens):
            return self._tokens[prospective_index]
        return None

    def _advance(self, offset: int) -> None:
        self._token_index += offset
```

Here's `sample_parser.py`:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .lookahead_parser import LookaheadParser, StateFunc


class SampleParser(LookaheadParser[str]):
    def __init__(self, raw_text: str):
        self._raw_text = raw_text
        self._state = self._state_first

    def parse(self) -> None:
        self._parse()

    def _state_first(self, token: str) -> StateFunc:
        pass  # stub


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass  # stub
```

I'm running Python 3.9.6, but it was also happening in 3.9.5. The problem occurs whether I use `_T` or `T`, in case you're looking askance at that. mypy itself is not reporting any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You only import `lookahead_parser` if `TYPE_CHECKING` is true. That variable is false at runtime, so the module never gets loaded. Just remove the `if TYPE_CHECKING:` part and do the import unconditionally.

```
from .lookahead_parser import LookaheadParser, StateFunc
```

Comment: Eeks! Thank you! I should have seen that. But now I get `TypeVar` is not defined when I run python. It seems that flake8 and mypy are not sufficient to tell me whether the code has the definitions it needs. I'm running VSCode because PyCharm didn't handle type hints well.

Comment: Pulling all imports out of TYPE_CHECKING solved this problem. I just wish I could be told of these problems before runtime. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just avoid the variable `TYPE_CHECKING` for now. It lets you do advanced metaprogramming tricks and circumvent the type checker, and I doubt you'll need any of that for a bit anyway.

Comment: I'm finding that all of my other problems with using types are resolving by pulling imports out of TYPE_CHECKING. I started using TYPE_CHECKING to get around apparent cyclic dependencies using types in PyCharm. It seems that I should have stopped using TYPE_CHECKING when I switched to VSCode and mypy, as type hints now seem to behave as documented. Thanks again!

Comment: I did have to add `if TYPE_CHECKING` back in for a few modules, but at least now it makes sense -- those modules each included the other.